# javascript variable concatenation in loop

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, concatenation

How am I supposed to concatenate this?

here's my javascript code

```
var c0 = document.all.ntext.value; 
var c1 = document.all.stext.value;
var x;

for(x=0; x<2; x++)
{
    a.innerHTML = c //contatenation needed
}
```

Comment: why use looping? instead of a.innerHTML = c0 + c1;

Comment: Don't use `document.all`, it is a non-standard IE4ism.

Comment: Remember this: Everytime you want to use numbered variables it will be the right time to start learning about arrays

Answer (score 1):

```
var c0 = document.all.ntext.value; 
var c1 = document.all.stext.value;
var x;

for(x=0; x<2; x++)
{
    a.innerHTML = c0 + с1
}
```

Is that what you want?

It'll be much better if you'll go this way:

```
var c = [document.all.ntext.value, document.all.stext.value];
var x;

for(x=0; x<c.length; x++)
{
    a.innerHTML += c[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var needed = ['ntext', 'stext'];   
a.innerHTML = needed.map(function(key) {
  return document.all[key].value;
}).join('');
```

[.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) need a shim for old browsers.